# What is a good algorithm for searching a string for multiple substrings?

Tags: string, algorithm, search

To be more exact, I'm looking for an algorithm that will take two collections of strings, and return all elements from the first collection which contain all elements from the second collection.

e.g. If I have ["cat", "dog", "boy"], it would return, say, "The boy wants a cat and a dog", but not, for example, "The dog is a good boy."

I found the Aho-Corasick algorithm but that seems to be better for an "at least one match" instead of an "every match" solution.

Comment: Whole words only? What about "the boy catapulted the dog over the wall"?

Comment: I was pretty unclear about it. My particular instance is for whole words only, but I thought a general purpose algorithm would be easier to ask about. The intent is something similar to searching through forums for posts with given content, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the specifics of the questions but assuming you have

`collection1 : ['this is a good boy',' this is a bad boy',....]`

and

`collection2: ['this', 'is a', 'good', 'boy']`

it should only return `'this is a good boy'`.

Again, I am not sure about the memory and speed requirements of such an algorithm but I would create a suffix tree to validate element existence :

psuedo code

```
for elm1 in collection1:
  sTree = suffix_tree(elm)
  valid = false
  for elm2 in collection2:
    valid = valid & search_in_suffix(elm2)
  if valid:
    return elm1
return 'NOT_FOUND'
```

you can read more about the suffix tree [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree). Please keep in mind that it also depends on your dataset, if you have really large strings, suffix tree might be quick but creating it would cost you a lot of memory.

Answer (score 0):

The Aho-Corasick automaton can work here if we slightly modify it.

1. Let's build the Aho-Corasick automaton for the second collection of the strings.
2. If one string in the automaton is a prefix of the other, we can remove it. It won't change the answer.
3. Let's traverse the automaton using only initial edges (it's a tree this way) and precompute a node that is an ancestor of the given one and corresponds to an end of some string from the collection for each node (I'll denote it as `anc_end`. It's unique as no string is a prefix of any other as shown above). We can do it in linear time using depth first search (the parameters are the current node and the last node that corresponds to the end of some string we've seen on the path from the root to this node (or -1 if there's no such node)).
4. We can traverse the automaton as we would normally do for each string of the first collection. We need to set `was[anc_end[v]] = true` at each step where `v` is the current node. We just need to check that `was` is `true` for all nodes corresponding to the end of some string in the second collection when we're done.
5. We're almost there. Instead of initializing the `was` array for every string with the new collection, we'll use "array with version" structure (the idea is to keep a pair (value, timestamp) instead of just the value and increment the timer when we go to the next string)) and count the number of seen "end" nodes (we need to reset the counter to zero for each string from the first collection).

This solution is linear in the size of the input, so it's optimal in terms of time complexity (it also uses a linear amount of space).